# Lightswitch Organizational Chart

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

**Situation:**

1. I have an application that have Employee information
2. Each Employee has a Manager field (that refers to another employee)
3. To enhance the experience, I was thinking of placing an organization chart based on the inputted information.

**Question:**

1. Is there a way to dynamically generate an organizational chart based on Employee-Manager information in Lightswitch? I know I will recurse on the relationships, however I'm unsure on how to present it.
2. If it's not possible in a graphical format, would it be possible to have it represented in a grid?
3. Would it be possible through creating a custom control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have create a custom control to work with hierarchies. You can see some [screen shots and source code](http://beutil.blogspot.com/2011/09/lightswitch-trees_18.html).

The custom control is based on [Karol Zadora msdn post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lsextensibility/thread/bcdaa86f-459a-47d3-853a-3c5e56eb088a/).

Comment: got to try it out, it's great and fully customizable too!

Comment: @Bryan Hong, if you need some help dont hesitate to contact to me.